# Problem with Game Icons in Ubuntu Dock

Tags: gnome-shell, .desktop, ubuntu-dock

So, I made a **stardew valley.desktop** and add this shortcut to favorites.

But when I start the game, the game creates a new icon and replaces mine with that one instead.

[image]

How I can fix this?